# Data connection keeps turning on in Alcatel One Touch?

Tags: data-connection

I have an Alcatel One Touch. The data connection is turning on by itself in the past couple of months.

I went to see Bell today, and the guy said it could be an app that's turning it on?

How do I check this? I really do not want to delete my apps or loose all my important texts messages. Is there an app that I can check which  is turning on my data connection?

Comment: There are many phones named with Alcatel One Touch. Which exact model are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**Introductory:** Have you tried going into **Settings** >> **Mobile Data** and de-selecting **Mobile Data**? Normally, when you install apps from Google Play, the **App Permissions** will tell you what apps have network access. Having said that, it could be any number of applications turning on your Data.

**Second Possible Solution:** You may also want to try disabling automatic connection by pursuing the following action. go to **Settings** >> **More Connections** > **Mobile Networks** > **Network Mode**. Make sure that none of the modes have **automatic connection** enabled.

**Answering Your Questions:** As far as I'm concerned, you can download [Permissions Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carlocriniti.android.permission_explorer&hl=en) to see what apps are capable of accessing your Data.

Good luck and let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I've downloaded the app you mention. What exactly am I looking for ? Access-data-statues?

Comment: Not a problem. Well, yes, anything that has the word 'network' in it should be of some relevance, but you'll really have to play around and see what you think could be causing it.  There is also an app called MobiWol. It's a no-root Firewall app. So, once you find the potential apps, download MobiWol and disallow it from connecting to the internet.